# mysql-workbench on Slackware 13.37 KDE error

Tags: mysql, kde-plasma, slackware

After many hours of installing various libraries on my Slackware 13.37 i managed to start mysql-workbench (but I was wrong).
When launched from command line i get this warning:

```
bash-4.2# mysql-workbench
** Message: Gnome keyring daemon seems to not be available. Stored passwords will be lost once quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_ssh.py", line 43, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
Warning! Can't use connect with timeout in paramiko None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_grt.py", line 27, in <module>
    import wb_admin_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_main.py", line 29, in <module>
    import wb_admin_monitor
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_monitor.py", line 21, in <module>
    import wba_monitor_be
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wba_monitor_be.py", line 26, in <module>
    import wb_admin_ssh
  File "/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_ssh.py", line 119, in <module>
    log_warning(_this_file, 'Cannot use connect with timeout in paramiko version %s\n' % paramiko.__version__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__version__'
** Message: Failed loading module '/usr/local/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_grt.py' (python)
Ready.
```

the main program window appear and when i try to make a new connection i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 14, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko

** (mysql-workbench-bin:2919): WARNING **: Tunnel manager could not be executed
```

and a popup appears:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root Cannot
>   start SSH tunnel manager

mysql and ssh is installed and configured correctly:

```
bash-4.2# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

bash-4.2# ssh -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
```

can someone help me please !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you that the [python-paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) module is missing. It is a python module for SSH connections; apparently that is used by one of the MySQL Workbench features. Get the slackware package [here](http://sotirov-bg.net/slackpack/pack.cgi?id=850) and install it executing

```
sudo installpkg paramiko-1.7.6-noarch-1gds.txz
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am not a slackware expert... But I doubt that you have to reinstall the Workbench. you can test if the python package is installed correctly by starting the python console and importing it.

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new ... to install python modules. The problem was that the module pycrypto used by paraiko  was not installed correctly

Comment: On Debian 6.x, this was the only missing library to fix the ssh tunnel issue for the mysql-workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer above. On 64 bit systems, you have to install specific 32 bit libraries for workbench to work. E.g I had to install 32 bit python alongside the 64 bit python.
Also common errors include distribution specific errors. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" not found, I created a soft link from /etc/my.cnf. Also had to create a folder at /root/.mysql/workbench/log for workbench to launch